# aurelia - dropdown not selecting value from db on load

Tags: aurelia, dropdown

I am using aurelia and have a dropdown. It passes the GroupId correctly back into my save function however it isnt selecting anything when editing a item.

```
return this.dataContext.getBaseContent(this.id)
                        .then(baseContent => this.baseContent = baseContent);

<dropdown disabled.bind="readonly" options.bind="core.GetVariableGroups()" selected.bind="baseContent.GroupId" />
```

HTML of dropdown

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 877px;" title="">
   <a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1">
      <span>Choose an option...</span>
      <div><b></b></div>
   </a>
   <div class="chosen-drop">
      <div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
      <ul class="chosen-results">
         <li class="active-result au-target" data-option-array-index="1">Option 1</li>
         <li class="active-result au-target" data-option-array-index="2">Option 2</li>
         <li class="active-result au-target" data-option-array-index="3">Option 3</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>

<template>
    <select disabled.bind="disabled" class="form-control" data-placeholder.bind="placeholder" value.bind="selected">
        <option repeat.for="option of options" value.bind="option.Id" text.bind="option.Name"></option>
    </select>
</template>

{"$type":"Admin.Contracts.Pocos.Development.ApplicationVariables.BaseContentModel, Admin.Contracts","Id":441,"GroupId":1,"GroupName":"Option 1"
```

**Ive found the issue, unsure how to solve it. Its already bond the values before it goes off and grab the data from the db. I need it to rebind on 'complete' unsure how to do this though.**

Comment: Could you post a sample of the returned json. Thanks.

Comment: More information required.  Looks like you're not using a standard `select` element.. what drop-down library are you using?  Try setting up your scenario in the [aurelia plunker](http://bit.ly/aurelia-plunker) to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Can I ask why this has been marked down? Unsure what I have done wrong

Comment: Seems like a perfectly reasonable question, I'm encountering the same issue and am not enamored with the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is required: add just below the constructtor, you need to trigger a chosen:update.

```
selectedChanged(){
    // if chosen item isnt = selected then set it
    var currentSelected = $('select', this.element).find(':selected').val();
    if(currentSelected != this.selected) {

        if(this.options.some(o => o.Id == this.selected)){
            $('select', this.element).val(this.selected);
            $('select', this.element).trigger("chosen:updated");
        }
        else{
            // new selected isnt in list of options..
            // set back to prev value
            this.selected = currentSelected;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the documentation on `selectedChanged`?  Why wouldn't Aurelia handle this for me?  So for EVERY select with previous values I have to do this?  That kind of defeats the purpose of a framework.

Comment: I am stuck on the same problem, I have a select list where the value is either true or false and I still can't get Aurelia to select the proper item based on the value for the property I am binding to's value from the database. Very frustrating.